# how strip commas from string in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I wonder how to remove commas from given string. My try was:

```
st = "1,2,3"
String.strip(st, ?,)
#=> "1,2,3"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`String.strip/2` only removes characters at the beginning and end of the string. I believe you're looking for [**`String.replace/4`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#replace/4). Use it like this:

```
String.replace("1,2,3", ",", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
st |> String.split(",") |> Enum.join
```

Of course it's best to use the standard tool, but then this is an alternative.